# Can I use a PHP framework without index.php or MVC?

Tags: php, authentication, scripting, frameworks, crud

Is there a PHP framework that doesn't force me to use a single [index.php](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/overview/appflow.html) as the entry point, or an [MVC architecture](http://cakephp.org/pages/features)? Because I need to develop something in my own way, with features like Authentication, Security, Crypto, Database CRUD and the like, and so a framework of some sort could help. Is this RAD?

Comment: If you need to develop something in your own way you should probably develop it your self. Just a thought.

Comment: Yea, but will a framework not help implement the features that I need?

Comment: Like I said below use zend as a library and you are good to go.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[The Zend framework](http://framework.zend.com) will let you use whatever jacked-up system you can create. It is modular; use what you want throw away the rest. Using the MVC pattern is a good idea however. Remember you stand on the shoulders of giants.

Comment: Remember Zend is very modular. If you just want to use Zend_Auth, you can use it without MVC. Zend MVC is just another module (well a way of organizing the modues with some glue really).

Comment: Just curious why you don't want to use single entry points? You will have pretty urls /user/add /user/delete /user/show-profile etc....

Comment: Zend seems huge. Take authentication / login for example. How do I only create a basic system for user accounts, without the rest of the framework?

Comment: Zend Framework is the way to go if there's portions of the Framework you want to build yourself.  The Magneto Ecommerce system is a good example of this.  While I'm a big MVC fan sometimes you'll understand existing frameworks (and their shortcomings) better once you've tried to develop your own.  We stand on the shoulders of giants, but sometimes the giant has syphilis.

Answer (score 1):

Also remember that front controller (index.php) and MVC are separate patterns. That is, you can have an MVC framework that does NOT implement or require the front controller. My framework of choice, [QCubed](http://qcu.be), happens to be like that.

Comment: +1 Thank you! This answer would do very well for my question as well: Please have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7827937/which-php-frameworks-do-not-use-a-front-controller/7829356#7829356