# Which PHP frameworks do NOT use a front controller?

Tags: php

It seems the more popular frameworks use a front controller. I understand the benefits of a front controller (reduces redundancy and simplifies extensibility), but

I want to know what PHP frameworks do NOT use a front controller. Additionally I am interested in those frameworks that use page controllers and that recommend using a real file directory structure for the urls as opposed to rewriting almost every url or using a mess of a query string. Additionally I am interested in knowing which of the frameworks that do not use a front controller implement MVC. Lastly, any additional details you can provide on the non-front-controller frameworks would be useful, particularly what version of PHP it uses or requires. (I know I can get this later information from other sites so it is not as important.)

Consider [the words of Rasmus Lerdorf](http://toys.lerdorf.com/archives/38-The-no-framework-PHP-MVC-framework.html) (the original creator of PHP):

> "As for MVC, if you use it carefully, it can be useful in a web
>   application. Just make sure you avoid the temptation of creating a
>   single monolithic controller. A web application by its very nature is
>   a series of small discrete requests. If you send all of your requests
>   through a single controller on a single machine you have just defeated
>   this very important architecture. Discreteness gives you scalability
>   and modularity. You can break large problems up into a series of very
>   small and modular solutions and you can deploy these across as many
>   servers as you like. You need to tie them together to some extent most
>   likely through some backend datastore, but keep them as separate as
>   possible. This means you want your views and controllers very close to
>   each other and you want to keep your controllers as small as possible." - Rasmus Lerdorf

UPDATE: Many thanks to user [Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16668/alex) for the first of hopefully more answers. His answer is QCubed ..

> "remember that front controller (index.php) and MVC are separate
>   patterns. That is, you can have an MVC framework that does NOT
>   implement or require the front controller. My framework of choice,
>   QCubed, happens to be like that." - [Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16668/alex)

Now if we can reopen this question then we can continue what we started and put together a list of frameworks that do not use a front controller. Please vote to reopen. Thank you.

Comment: I think I can safely say that there are no MVC frameworks that do not use a C

Comment: @SyntaxError Django uses MTV (Model-Template-View) there's no controller. Well they use the view as a controller =S .. I love php

Comment: @Syntax Error Of course any MVC framework will use a controller. I am interested in frameworks that do no use a FRONT controller (notice I am particularly interested in frameworks that use page controllers in the place of a front controller).

Comment: I think one can hardly achieve Inversion of Control without a front controller, and Inversion of Control is the main characteristic of a framework, isn't it? Which means an MVC framework without a front controller is not really a framework, but a library.

Comment: @greg0ire Inversion of control would work for page controllers the same way it would for a front controller. A front controller is really just a page controller for EVERY "page." A page controller can work like a front controller (by being the first point of control for various "pages") and indeed in many cases it is implemented that way. Both can be used in MVC. Just as a front controller can pass the control on, a page controller can do the same.

Comment: +1 for the good question, but I don't understand how you can have Inversion of Control if you write the page controllers yourself. Usually, you don't write a front controller yourself, which means your code is called by the framework and not the other way round.

Comment: I have thought about this same question at one time, would like to see some answers

Answer (score 0):

I'm still learning Symfony2, so if I'm not wrong, i think you can have different front controllers. And the code would be separated in different Bundles.

By default, it has two fron controllers, one for production and the other one for development. However i think you can create more than one (one for each page)

Hope this helps

Comment: As you say Symfony2, uses at least one front controller. The question is about MVC frameworks that use *no* front controller. -1

Comment: but if you create as many front controllers as page it would be like using pages controllers... you'd have pages like mysite.com/home.php, mysite.com/products.php, mysite.com/contact.php.. where they are all different files (controllers) using different boundles... i thought that's what you were looking for

Comment: @pleasedontbelong Thanks for the answer. Indeed page controllers are basically like multiple front controllers.. but I am not convinced that Symfony2 recommends making new page controllers for a site.

Comment: Maybe you could, but that would be twisting sf2 and really isn't the purpose of Symfony2's front controllers. The OP is looking for a framework which normally works like you described in your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question, although I am not sure what your end game is. A controller basically 'bootstraps' the framework into a useable state. My experience lies with Symfony, Zend, and CakePHP, and can tell you that the controllers used in Symfony are quite short (~50 lines of code). However the underlying code is quite extensive, but this code does a number of things such as setup your ORM, cache heavily used arrays (creating static files in /cache directory), and initialize an autoloader for file calls, just to name a few.

Within the Symfony Framework context you have a primary controller, but you also have mini-controllers, or as you put it, page controllers, these controllers are referred to as 'actions'. An action acts as a bridge between a user request and various attributes of your application which may include file/data stores, request handling, user redirects etc. As with the primary controller the actions are meant to be lightweight, mainly consisting of API calls to underlying classes and functions.

I have actually used Zend within Symfony to fill the gaps in functionality that Symfony does not provide. So to your question, I am using Zend functionality without any controller interaction. All I need to do is initialize Zend within the autoloader (b/c Zend is correctly namespaced). Also did this with CakePHP to take advantage of the Inflector class, no controller usage, just calls to functionality I didn't want to write myself.